# Update query running but not updating table php

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

Here's the code i am using withing a for loop which run 10 times:

```
$query = "UPDATE fblikes SET likes = '$var[$i]' WHERE link = '$web[$i]'";

if(mysql_query($query))
{
    echo $query;
}                         
else
{
    echo mysql_error();
}
```

The code runs, I do get `ok!` printed 10 times but nothing happens in the table. I also checked the 2 arrays i.e. `$var` and `$web`, they contain the correct values.

The query looks okay to me. Here's what i got (one of the 10 outputs) : `UPDATE fblikes SET likes = '5' WHERE link = 'xxxxxxx.com/xxxx/iet.php';`

Comment: The problem is `WHERE link = '$web[$i]'"`, you should escape that variable properly.

Comment: Why not to print the query itself, instead of meaningless "ok"?

Comment: @MahmoudGamal what do u mean by escape that variable? I dont understand

Comment: `mysql_real_escape_string()`

Comment: @YourCommonSense the query looks okay to me. Here's what i got (one of the 10 outputs) :    UPDATE fblikes SET likes = '5' WHERE link = 'http://xxxxxxx.com/xxxx/iet.php'

Comment: Please tell us the value of `mysql_affected_rows()` after the call to `mysql_query()`.

Comment: @gd1 the value of mysql_affected_rows() is 0

Comment: So the query is valid but the WHERE produces and empty set to be updated.

Comment: Try re-writing the query line like this: **$query = "UPDATE fblikes SET likes = '{$var[$i]}' WHERE link = '{$web[$i]}'";**

Comment: @gd1 but i checked the values in the table and the values which are coming up in the $web array, they are exactly the same

Comment: @itsols i tried your query as well but i got the same results, everything for the where is matching but still the table isn't getting updated

Comment: @Arihant From the way your query is written I'm guessing that you're working  on Windows. Is this tested on Windows as well or is it tested on Linux?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what the problem exactly is, and to figure out you should print the value of `$query`, and show us what you get. More, please tell us the value of `mysql_affected_rows()` after the call to `mysql_query()`.

However, your code implements some wrong patterns.

First of all, you are not escaping `$var[$i]` and `$web[$i]` with two potential effects:

- You can produce wrong queries
- You don't sanitize the input to the database, thus exposing your application to security issues

Moreover, you perform several similar queries that differ only on the inputs provided.

The solution, for both issues, is the use of prepared statements that will give you more control, security and performance. Consider abandoning `mysql_*` functions and switching to `mysqli_*` or `PDO`, and read about [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).